# rspec stub current_company

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, rspec, stub

I have a Rails 3 project in which I want to store the current company selected in a session variable.

I'm working with the staff controller spec and would like to stub out current_company for now as I'm isolating my spec example for the staff new controller action.

```
it "should call current_company" do 
  company = mock_model(Company, :id => "1")
  controller.should_receive(:current_company).and_return(company)
  get :new
end
```

Here is my new action for the staff controller

```
  def new
    @staff = Staff.new
    @staff.company_id = current_company.id
  end
```

I keep getting error

```
Failure/Error: get :new
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `current_company' for #<StaffsController:0x000000028d6ad8>
```

I've also tried just stubbing it out instead of using should_receive

```
  controller.stub!(:current_company).and_return(company)
```

I get the same error.

Comment: Where is current_company defined?

Comment: No where yet that's why I want to stub it out. I will end up in ApplicationController. If I put a method called current_company in my ApplicationController the error goes away, but is there a way to stub this out to Isolate my controller test?

Comment: You can stub it in your tests, but you can't attempt to use it in your application code if it doesn't exist. Stubbing is only for your test classes.

Comment: Ok so should I spec out my ApplicationController first and then write a method for current_company?

Comment: >> you can't attempt to use it in your application code if it doesn't exist <<  

Sure you can. That's the whole point of BDD -- write the specs first, then write the code.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. Thought his error was when interacting with the app, not the specs failing. @zetetic is correct, check your naming conventions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was bombing out on the 'should be successful' example/test, so I've put my stubbing in a before block.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe StaffsController do

  describe "GET 'new'" do
    let(:staff) { mock_model(Staff, :company_id= => nil)}
    let(:company) { mock_model(Company, :id => 1)}

    before do
      Staff.stub!(:new).and_return(staff)
      controller.stub!(:current_company).and_return(company)
    end

    it "should be successful" do
      get :new
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should call current_company" do 
      controller.should_receive(:current_company).and_return(company)
      get :new
    end
  end
end
```

This works for:

```
class StaffsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @staff = Staff.new
    current_company.id
  end
end
```

Comment: What is the `new` action supposed to do, exactly? The value from `current_company.id` is not assigned to anything.

Comment: ah this is my next problem. I'm now writing a test to assign current_company.id to @staff.company_id so I can store it in a hidden field with in the form and so it will create that link (staff belongs_to company) when crating a staff member.

It's too messy to explain in a comment, I think I might extract this out to another question.

Comment: @zeteic My next test will be:
`it "should assign staff.company_id to 1" do
      staff.should_receive(:company_id=).with(1)
      get :new
end`

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine to me, it should work. There must be some other problem we are not seeing. I notice the controller name is "StaffsController" -- is that correct? Double-check the names of the controller and the corresponding spec -- they should be the same.